# Does the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality imply 2-positivity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, complete-positivity, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Recall the following generalisation of Cauchy–Schwarz.

> **Theorem.** Let $f\colon \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$ be a linear 2-positive map between C$^*$-algebras.  Then for all $a,b \in \mathscr{A}$ we have $f(b^*a)\ f(a^*b) \leq \| f(a^*a)\| \ f(b^*b)$.

Does the converse hold?

> **Question.** Let $f\colon \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$ be a linear positive map between C$^*$-algebras such that for all $a,b \in \mathscr{A}$ we have $f(b^*a)\ f(a^*b) \leq \| f(a^*a)\| \ f(b^*b)$.  Is $f$ 2-positive?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this general form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?  I know how to show it in the case $a=1$ but I must admit to being puzzled by how to get this more general case.

Comment: It's an exercise in Paulsen's "Completely Bounded Maps And Operators Algebras".  As he did not include a proof, we published one in an appendix of a paper where we needed it: Theorem 55 of http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/57/9/10.1063/1.4961526 . The statement is kind of folklore though.